# What are the patterns and anti-patterns when programming for EOS?

Tags: smart-contract, eosjs, best-practices

When programming smart contracts or writing `eosjs` code, there are certain pitfalls that you might fall into if you are not careful. What are some of the patterns and anti-patterns to be aware of that specifically affect EOSIO code?

Answer (score 1):

## Check who receives a transfer when notifying a contract

If you have code which is activated upon receipt of a notification. For example:

`[[eosio::on_notify("eosio.token::transfer")]] void transfer(eosio::name const & from, eosio::name const & to, eosio::asset const & quantity, std::string const & memo);`

Then you should check that the `to` field is actually this contract, and do nothing otherwise:

```
void mycontract::transfer(eosio::name const & from, eosio::name const & to, eosio::asset const & quantity, std::string const & memo)
{
  if(to != get_self()) return;
  // Process the transfer
}
```

This prevents people forwarding notifications for transactions that do not involve your contract, and tricking your contract into thinking that they have indeed sent money to you.

## Check that the asset received truly is the one you expect

In EOSIO, anyone can make any asset and give it any name they want. So if I choose to, I can call an asset called `EOS` on my personal smart contract based on `eosio.token`, issue myself a billion of them, and then try to trick smart contracts that don't check for this vulnerability. This will affect your code if you accept multiple tokens for different reasons, using:

`[[eosio::on_notify("*::transfer")]] void transfer(eosio::name const & from, eosio::name const & to, eosio::asset const & quantity, std::string const & memo);`

You can check which token you are receiving with the following code:

```
void mycontract::transfer(eosio::name const & from, eosio::name const & to, eosio::asset const & quantity, std::string const & memo)
{
  if(get_first_receiver() != eosio::name("eosio.token")) return;
}
```